# Return row(s) if SUM of a column reaches to certain number

Tags: mysql

This is mybb_reputation table

[image: mybb_reputation table]

I want to fetch number of row(s) `rid` if the sum of `reputation` of all these rows reaches to 3. For example in this case (please see the image above) if I run a query it should either return rid 1, 2 and 3 (so the total reputation becomes 3) or either it returns only rid 5 because its reputation is exactly equals to 3

I've tried running this query;

```
SELECT * FROM mybb_reputation WHERE SUM(reputation) = 3;
```

but due to limited knowledge in MySQL its showing error e.g.: #1111 - Invalid use of group function

Please help!

Comment: How does your grouping work?  Most of the answers assume you mean to check the reputation of a set of rows that share a common field value.   For instance, why wouldn't you want rows 6 &7, they add to 3

Comment: @AgRizzo, if the sum of reputation is exactly equals to 3 then whether it return rid 1,2,3 OR only rid 5 OR rid 6,7 , it should be fine.

Comment: (Just my opinion but..)  I think it is impossible to give you a solution that will find every possible combination.  Finding 1 row equaling 3 is easy.  Finding 2, not that difficult, but you wind up with a Cartesian product, checking the sum to be equal to 3.  Checking for any 3 records is much more difficult.  Do you have any constraints beyond 3?  How about the records must be sequential?

Comment: Can you export the table and data and place this here? http://sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM mybb_reputation GROUP BY rid HAVING SUM(reputation) = 3 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. But if I use 4 instead of 3 then it returns only rid 7 which has only 2 reputation

Comment: Until I find a correct answer I'm accepting this since its closely resemble to what I want. Thanks for all others who replied.

Answer (score 1):

This answer goes with my comments -

Find 1 record (easy)

```
SELECT tmp1.rid AS rid
FROM mybb_reputation AS tmp1
WHERE tmp1.reputation = 3;
```

Find any 2 records (Using the < because the order of the relationship is not relevant to an answer)

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',',tmp1.rid, tmp2.rid) AS rid
FROM mybb_reputation AS tmp1
JOIN mybb_reputation AS tmp2
  ON tmp1.rid < tmp2.rid
WHERE tmp1.reputation + tmp2.reputation = 3
```

Find any 3 records (same idea as before regarding <)

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',',tmp1.rid, tmp2.rid, tmp3.rid) AS rid
FROM mybb_reputation AS tmp1
JOIN mybb_reputation AS tmp2
  ON tmp1.rid < tmp2.rid
JOIN mybb_reputation AS tmp3
  ON tmp2.rid < tmp3.rid
WHERE tmp1.reputation + tmp2.reputation + tmp3.reputation = 3
```

Find 4 (algorithm just repeats)

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',',tmp1.rid, tmp2.rid, tmp3.rid, tmp4.rid) AS rid
FROM mybb_reputation AS tmp1
JOIN mybb_reputation AS tmp2
  ON tmp1.rid < tmp2.rid
JOIN mybb_reputation AS tmp3
  ON tmp2.rid < tmp3.rid
JOIN mybb_reputation AS tmp4
  ON tmp3.rid < tmp4.rid
WHERE tmp1.reputation + tmp2.reputation + tmp3.reputation + tmp4.reputation = 3
```

You will need to continue this for however many combinations you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM mybb_reputation
GROUP BY uid
HAVING SUM(reputation) >= 3
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

Not sure about the exact order of this, but it should contain all conditions you will need.

And honestly, your data structure seems very weird to answer such queries.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to have the sum for a group. I'm going to assume you want to group by uid:

```
SELECT * FROM mybb_reputation 
WHERE uid in 
  (Select uid FROM mybb_reputation
   GROUP BY uid
   HAVING SUM(reputation) = 3);
```

If you want to select the individual rows that match some aggregate condition, you'll need a subquery. nested subquery finds the groups that have the desired condition. Then the outer query says to return each row that is in that group. The group has to be identified somehow, and in this case, we are using uid.

Some implementations of MySQL will treat this as a correlated subquery, which could be a problem if your table is large. If you have that problem, you can add one more layer of subselect to fix it:

```
SELECT * FROM mybb_reputation 
WHERE uid in 
  (SELECT * FROM
     (Select uid FROM mybb_reputation
      GROUP BY uid
      HAVING SUM(reputation) = 3));
```

or by using a join instead of a subquery:

```
SELECT r1.* FROM mybb_reputation r1,
     (Select uid FROM mybb_reputation
      GROUP BY uid
      HAVING SUM(reputation) = 3) r2
WHERE r1.uid = r2.uid;
```

Comment: You know that this kind off query will kill mysql (below version 5.6) performance on large tables? and most likly needs an complete table scan on table mybb_reputation in the outer query

Comment: Well, I know that I run this query just fine. However, it might be prudent to add how to uncorrelate the query for anyone that has an old implementation that treats that query as correlated.

Comment: Indeed the MySQL optimizer in version > 5.6 is alot better.. but JOIN (with correct indexes and without "Using temporary; Using filesort") will clearly outperform this IN statement construct with many records

Comment: I gave the answer I think is appropriate given the context of the question...part of the context includes the asker. "Premature optimization is the root of all evil."

Comment: Ok i can respect that.. this isn't Premature optimization just basic knowledge on how MySQL works with IN statements (correlated subquerys) it's even mentioned in the MySQL documentation..